# Black screen before my splash screen loads iphone

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

There is a strange problem occured in my application in which it's showing a black screen for a bit of time before it loads my splashscreen. This black screen is not due to any ongoing operation as I am loading my splashscreen first and then starting my xml parsing task.

I even tried using [window makeKeyAndVisible];, but in vain.

This' my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
    comingFromLogin = NO;
    //Check For Internet
    gotInternet = [self checkInternet]; //Test for Internet, calling the self method
    if ( gotInternet == 0) 
    {
        //I have no internet
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry No Network Available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        //  internetIcon.hidden = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        //I do have internet
        [self didLoadSplashScreen];
    }
}

-(void)didLoadSplashScreen
{
    activity_indicator = [[ActivityIndicator alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActivityIndicator" bundle:nil];
    splashScreen = [[splashScreenView alloc]initWithNibName:@"splashScreenView" bundle:nil];

    splashScreen.view.alpha = 1.0;
    splashScreen.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480);
    [window addSubview:splashScreen.view];
    [window addSubview:activity_indicator.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self disappearSplashScreen];
}
```

Can anybody please help?

This black screen stays for about 2 seconds. I'm running it on iOS4.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the default loading behavior! The `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method isn't run until the application FINISHED LOADING.

The way to overcome this is to have a picture the size of the view and call it `Default.png` that will show instead of the black screen.