# Black Screen at the start of iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift

i have a problem. when i launch my app there is a black screen viewed for a seconds then the launch screen appeared.

my splash screen isn’t the default one. i used view controller because my splash had an animation.

i searched for a solution, and i get this on:

[Black screen before my splash screen loads iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759585/black-screen-before-my-splash-screen-loads-iphone)

but it didn’t worked

any help please?

thanks

Comment: We'll probably need to see some code or a link to a GitHub repo if the project is a public one.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDiLorenzo but the problem not with splash or any  view i think the problem with the app settings or some :(

Comment: You need to post the the code in your ViewController for anyone here to be able to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you selected your Launch Screen in your target's `App Icons and Launch Images` ?

Edit: If you don't use any launch (splash) screen or image then, a black screen is the default behaviour before loading your view controller.

[image]

Comment: i'm starting with initial viewController i'm not using the default splash

Comment: For some time now, you can build a custom xib file and use it as a launch screen. In my answer I've showed you where you can select that custom file in order for your app to use it. Those settings are not using any default files.

Comment: If you're starting with a view controller without any launch image or screen, then this is the default behaviour when launching an app (a black screen for a few seconds).

Comment: Thanks @Razvan i'm using view controller bcuz i have animation in the splash 
so is there any way to get ride of this problem?

Comment: @Tony how you solved the problem ?  because i am still geting black screen for few seconds inspite of i have set my Controller as default Launch screen File.

Comment: I solved it by getting an image of the first frame of the animation, set it in the launchImage, let it launch, once its done my animation starts and it gives a feel like its all the animation.

Comment: For me, the issue was that I had something in the "Launch Screen File" screen while I was using LaunchImage. Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue but my solution is different,
I've made an extension of `UINavigationController` to make `UINavigationBar` clear.
So,the problem is , I was doing some R&D on that code and unknowingly put a method

```
open override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

    }
```

and from that time, I started facing this issue.

My advice, please double check that you haven't don't something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom splash screen to launch. But the Launch Screen file was pointed to Default `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Replaced that with my original custom splash, the issue fixed

[image]